# IIS Rewire URL regular expression

Tags: wcf, iis, url-rewriting, arr

I have multiple services at **Internal.com/Services** . As the name suggests this is an internal page, not accessible from outside. 
I have setup a site, **external.com**, where i will add a Reverse Proxy rule to rewrite to **Internal.com/Services**.

The problem I have now is that different services in Internal.com are hosted like this:

*interal.com/Services/oneService.svc*

*internal.com/Services/anotherService.svc*

This is the exact mapping i need from **external.com** server

**external.com/oneService.svc** ---> *interal.com/Services/oneService.svc*
**external.com/anotherService.svc** ---> *internal.com/Services/anotherService.svc*

How can i achieve this when setting the reverse proxy rule in IIS?

Answer (score 0):

Burned too many hours on this, but this solved it for me. Changing the .Net framework version for the application pool for the remote proxy site to 'no managed code'. 
Notice that rewriting in my case only failed when it came to .svc files. Regular html worked fine.

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/66974/iis-reverse-proxy-failing-on-svc-pages-and-some-other-pages-works-fine-for-pla